# JQueryMobile grouping buttons in the header / footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, markup

I have seen documentation on the JQueryMobile site that shows you how to group links in the header/footer together. I have also seen documents that allow you to place links specifically in the space to the left and/or right of the heading tag. I have NOT seen any documents on how to merge them

Basically what I want is

```
<div data-role="header">
  <a href="#" data-icon="gear">left 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-icon="gear">left 2</a>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <a href="#" data-icon="gear">right 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-icon="gear">right 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-icon="gear">right 3</a>
</div>
```

and for that to appear as

```
 [left 1][left 2]           Page Title           [right 1][right 2][right 3]
```

I have tried wrapping the links in a div and using floats (adding the class(s) `ui-btn-left/right` also appears to work), however the anchor tags remain as-is and the styles defined by the framework are never applied (All I see is regular links, no fancy buttons)

Can someone please tell me if I'm missing an attribute? or if there is a container class that I can use that will not block the buttons from having their new markup applied?

---

**Edit:**
The above code will ***currently*** output

```
 [left 1]           Page Title           [left 2]
 [right 1][right 2][right 3]
```

Comment: the only solution I have found is physically writing out the markup required for the buttons and placing that in the `float` container. I don't like having to write all of that extra html..

Comment: This should work out of the box. Can you try setting the `href` attributes to valid URLs instead of `#`? That might be the reason why the toolkit doesn't transform your links.

Comment: see my update above. Note: changing the `href` attribute did nothing.. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

Use a wrapping container to fix the position left or right aligned (I am using the class `ui-btn-[left/right]`) then force the link to take the markup with `data-role="button"`

So it looks like

```
<div data-role="header">
  <div class="ui-btn-left">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">left 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">left 2</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <div class="ui-btn-right">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">right 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">right 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">right 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give my -2 point back                                    use the class "ui-btn-right"/ "ui-btn-left" I have tested it only with one button in each side so I didnt tested with multiple buttons :) . Thnx anyway, i learned somehting

Comment: Update your answer. It is still wrong ;) _also, you cannot change your vote ( unless the answer is updated )_

Answer (score 2):

use the class "ui-btn-right"/ "ui-btn-left"

Update use wrapers for multiple buttons

```
<div class="ui-btn-left">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">left 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">left 2</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: then all of the links layer over eachother. using said class will only work if applied to a single button or a container with all buttons in them. and.. like noted.. the container solution fails because the framework misses the links when marking up the buttons.

Comment: ups sorry didnt have time to test I am trying now. :(

Comment: That made things worse. Again the button markup was not applied by the framework and the positioning was all left oriented. nothing on the right side.

Comment: Correction: The markup for the buttons was applied. But the positioning is still way off. the two sets of buttons and the header are blocking eachother and forcing new lines. So line1: buttons1, line2: header, line3: buttons2 (left aligned)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div data-role="header">
  <div class="ui-btn-left" data-role="controlgroup">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">left 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">left 2</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">right 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">right 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">right 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. You can also add a css rule like this:

div.ui-btn-left a {
 padding: 0;
}

div.ui-btn-right a {
 padding: 0;
}

... so it looks much better.